# oracle SQL search

Tags: sql, oracle

I have information of one data in table. I must find one data in same table, but in a different row.

Example:

t1

```
a b   c
----------
1 111 abc
2 222 abc
3 567 abc
```

t2

```
id d1 d2 d3
-----------
12 23 123 4,5
12 24 234 13,65
12 25 345 13,65
12 26 456 0
12 27 567 0
```

```
select t1.a, t1.b, t2.id 
from t1, t2 
where t1.b = t2.d2
```

How to get 13,65 (I know that d1 must be 25 (constant)) in a same select?

Thank you for answer.

Comment: Why do you expect `13,65`?  The join you have shown us, would only return the row with `d2 = 567, d3 = 0`. There is no value in `t2.d2` that matches the values in `t1.b` where `d3 = 13,65`.

Comment: I have same Id and I know that d1 is 25 and I must find 13,56.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: If you "know" that d1 is 25, then why don't you simply use `select * from t2 where d1 = 25`?

Comment: This question is confusing. Perhaps there is a better data example you could give where the keys actually match up with the description. I suggest you think about your problem and try to frame it in a way that someone could follow through the steps. You may find you answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need the Outer join. Tr this

```
select t1.a, t1.b, t2.id 
from t1, t2 
 where t1.b = t2.d2(+)
 and t2.d1 = '25'
```

Comment: Please stop using the old, outdated implicit joins in the where clause - especially for outer joins. Even Oracle recommends to stop using the proprietary `(+)` operator

Answer (score 0):

I did it with:

```
select t1.a, t1.b, ta1.id, ta2.d3 from t1 right join t2 ta1 on t1.b = ta1.d2, t2 ta2 where t1.b = 567 and ta1.id = ta2.id and ta2.d1 = 25;
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with multiples joins :

```
select t1.a, t1.b, t2.id, A.d3 
from t1

join t2 
on t1.b = t2.d2 --first join to get the t2.id linked with data from t1

  join (select t2.id, t2.d3
        from t2 
        where t2.d1 = 25
        and t2.id = (select distinct t2.id
                     from t2
                     left outer join t1
                     on t1.b = t2.d2)
        ) A --2nd join to get the data from t2 with d1=25 with the join on the id
  on A.id = t2.id
```

Result :

```
A   B   ID   D3
3   567 12   13,65
```